# Display the name of the maximum salary holder (WITHOUT USING A SUBQUERY)

Tags: sql, oracle

Say there's a table

```
Name  Salary
Joe   4000
Steve 6000
```

I could just do this

```
select name from emp where salary = (select max(salary) from emp);
```

but is there a way to do this without using a subquery?? Please help.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using Oracle 10g and LIMIT doesn't work on it

Comment: Which dbms? (Differente functionality can be used for this.)

Comment: Wait sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using Oracle and LIMIT doesn't work on it.

Comment: Do you consider a derived table (`select * from (select .. from)`) a "subquery"? And why do you think you can't use a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the version of Oracle.

On Oracle 12 there is a new low limiting clause that can be used:

```
  SELECT name
  FROM emp
  ORDER BY salary desc
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

There are examples in documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABEAACC

On earlier versions it can't be done without using a subquery, but if you must then create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW emp_ordered AS
SELECT *
 FROM emp
ORDER BY salary desc;
```

and then query this view in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_ordered
WHERE rownum <=1
```

Comment: `rownum <=1` What is the use of `<` here?

Comment: You can use `rownum <2` or `rownum <=1` to get the first row

Comment: Wouldn't `rownum = 1` suffice? `<= 1` just adds confusion to beginners.

Comment: And what about the **duplicates**? Your query will **always** return only one row. When there are ties you should show them too. See my answer.

Comment: @Lait thank you very much for pointing that. Yes, you are right, `WITH TIES` option is usefull when duplicates are needed.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL answer (no dbms specified):

```
select Name, Salary
from emp
order by Salary desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

**Edit:** Will work with newer Oracle versions.

Answer (score 1):

In **`Oracle 12c`**, the **[top-n row limiting](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55645)** feature is introduced. Which allows to ORDER the rows without an additional subquery. So, no more dependency on ROWNUM and explicit sorting in a subquery.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT ename, sal FROM emp ORDER BY sal DESC
  2  FETCH FIRST 1 row only;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000

SQL>
```

**Update** Regarding **duplicate rows**

There is an option **WITH TIES** which will include the duplicate rows.

For example,

```
SQL> insert into emp(empno, ename, sal) values(1234, 'LALIT', 5000);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT ename, sal FROM emp ORDER BY sal DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000
LALIT            5000

SQL>
```

Comment: Does the WITH TIES take the ORDER BY columns into consideration?

Comment: ORDER BY will work the same way as it should. When there are duplicate values, the ordering is never guaranteed among the duplicate values. In the above example, the two rows have sal value `5000` and thus selected on top, however, there is no guarantee of the two rows to be in a particular order always as they are ordered on sal.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when deciding if it's a tie or not.

Comment: When deciding the ties, all the ties are selected. But, the order among them is never guaranteed. There is a tie on sal with value `5000`, and both are selected. Rest all other rows with sal value less than 5000 are  not selected. However, there is no guarantee of order among the two selected rows. They are in random.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from emp order by salary DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Works for which dbms?

Comment: Sorry, seems like MySQL is the one supporting LIMIT. (Maybe some others as well.) But it's still not ANSI SQL. You can verify SQL standard compliant syntax here: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT name FROM emp
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this will not work for more than 1 employees having max salary

Comment: @cjava, wth that odd "without subquery" restriction I think this is as good as it gets.